Why Do Additive Categories Need Zero Objects? - Motivation
At the moment, I'm trying to develop intuition behind the derived construction of what is an additive category from the (standard) category definition.
(i) It seems natural that a category with the descriptor of "additive" would seek to include an additive binary operator on the Hom-sets (specifically one which acts analogously to the additive operator with respect to a group homomorphism between two abelian groups).
(ii) And the inclusion of the direct sum for all objects seems also natural, as now we can extend the definition of our additive operator from single Hom-sets to now refer toward morphisms with a shared codomain (i.e. we can define addition between $f\in\text{Hom}(X,Y),\ g\in\text{Hom}(Z,Y)$ via $f+g\in\text{Hom}(X\bigoplus Z,Y)$).
(iii) But as far as inclusion of a Zero Object is concerned...I struggle to find any algebraically enlightening reasons? (EDIT: I realize what follows is incorrect...but I will keep it included for the sake of preserving the original post.) An idea that came to mind was that the zero object can be defined as the direct sum and direct product consisting of all objects of a category: In this regard, the zero object can just been seen as the "ultimate" direct product/sum (which we already have established must exist as an object of the additive category in the finite cases. So the zero object is simply just the most extreme version of this direct sum/product property).
...though this doesn't feel extremely enlightening. If anybody has any other ideas, I would be happy to hear them! Thank you.

The zero object is not the direct sum of all objects in the category, it's the direct sum of no objects. The unique map $0\to Y$ is the one obtained by taking the empty sum of arrows to $Y$. We include it for the same reason we require groups to have identity elements.

@AlexKruckman I was actually just about to edit my initial post: Yes, you are correct. That's probably why I wasn't satisfied with that interpretation, because it's not correct. Thanks for the correction!

@AlexKruckman Also, to the second part of your comment...why? The way I view categories is that the morphisms represent the things with algebraic properties, with the objects solely providing a sort of "indexing" system to them (inheriting little to no algebraic behaviors). So being that we don't view objects algebraically, I don't see why we would want to include the "identity object".

(a) In general, you're correct that objects don't come with algebraic structure, but many important categorical properties do impose structure on the objects (e.g. products and coproducts, more generally limits and colimits, exponential objects, etc.). (b) Even if you aren't convinced by (a), you noticed yourself that direct sums are useful because they allow you to add objects with different domains. Given a family of arrows $(f_i\colon X_i\to Y){i\in I}$, we obtain $\sum{i\in I} f_i\colon \bigoplus_{i\in I} X_i\to Y$. When the family is empty, we obtain the zero map $0\to Y$.

So the zero object is necessary to complete the algebraic structure on arrows given by adding morphisms with different domains to include the case of the empty sum.

@AlexKruckman Perfect, I get it now! The part about the family being empty clicked it for me. Thank you so much again. (p.s. I'm also currently looking now at Abelian Categories, and I struggle to understand the generalization from algebra with the choice of term "abelian". if you have any quick ideas to share on that, I would be very grateful. But I can also just think on it, and you go on about your day. I'm thankful for the help you've already provided.)

I think the name "Abelian category" was chosen just because the definition of Abelian category is an abstraction of certain properties of the category of Abelian groups. So an Abelian category is one that behaves like the category of Abelian groups.
